# Why are my two iPads not merging distinct records in Ensembles?

Tags: ensembles

I have two (2) iPads that I am testing with.  The two iPads do NOT merge their contents at any time; for instance, I have 2 distinct records on iPad2 and 3 distinct records on iPad1, *and they remain this way forever*!

I determined this by taking a count of the records after Ensembles setup and again after viewDidLoad on the tableView and the contents remain consistent, unless I add a record which then *replaces* the latest record in the store, but the count remains the same.

Why are the two iPads not merging their distinct records?  And why when I add a record does it *replace* an existing record with a different key (SKU)?

Comment: Do they have objects have the same global ids? Ensembles will only merge objects with the same global id. Are you saying you end up with 5 objects on each device?

Comment: **FIXED!**  I mis-read the 'Book', (page 28)... In essence, I had two (2) *Dog* objects with the identifier 'snoopy', or in my case, each and every *book object* had the same identifier - "Books"... one of your users set me straight!  Now, onward and upward!  Thanks again for your help... I truly appreciate it!  SD